# We can see magnetic field lines but how about electric field lines?

Tags: electromagnetism, magnetic-fields, electric-fields

We can see magnetic field lines by putting compasses or iron filings around a wire that carries current, is there a way to see electric field lines so we can see electric field lines just like we can see magnetic field lines when we put compasses or iron filings around a wire?

Answer (score 9):

You can use, for example, grass seeds in oil.

See [this](https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=CoXCb1HHLJQ) video lecture, "Demo-by-Lewin(8.02-02-2): Display electric fields with grass seeds"

Update:

James Lincoln has some additional methods in these videos: “10 Ways to SEE the ELECTRIC FIELD ”[part1](https://youtu.be/Y6YdC2UoDYY) and [part2](https://youtu.be/bOLd2KVK-Mo).

Comment: Thank you, how about a single charge? Those in that video are two charges.

Comment: @SnoopyKid You can try to isolate the single “point charge” by moving the other objects away… For example, use a large ring with the point inside.

Comment: @SnoopyKid See https://youtu.be/7vnmL853784 at timestamp 2m30s.

Comment: thanks, how about this picture? https://0.academia-photos.com/attachment_thumbnails/37452010/mini_magick20180818-27420-1o69edd.png?1534620376

Comment: @SnoopyKid Possibly interesting: https://youtu.be/E25aX0w7C7I

Comment: That's really cool. I wonder if it is possible to see both electric field lines and magnetic field lines around a wire or anything at the same time, or will one of them dominate the other so that only a single field will be observed?

Comment: @SnoopyKid you can control the static charge on a wire (relative to something else) completely independently of the current running through it. That' treats the wire as a good conductor and therefore an equipotential. *However* you could also make your "wire" very high resistance by making it a long row of resistors soldered together. Then you would have an electric field *along* the wire...

Comment: ...but the problem then is that you would now have to dissipate a lot of power ($P = I \times V$) to get both a strong electric and strong magnetic field, and that would probably induce big convection currents in the oil that would make your seeds start to move around. It sounds pretty difficult. I recommend you ask that as a new question post so you can make space for new answer posts. I think it would be a great new question!

Comment: @robphy James Lincoln's videos are very helpful, is it somehow correct if I see and interpret electric sparks as how electric field lines will look like if we can see them

Comment: @SnoopyKid The location of the spark on the object indicates that the electric field is strong enough there to "ionize the air" so that air is no longer an insulator, but a conducting fluid. The path of the spark in the air is guided by the electric field, but also includes a lot of randomness [like in a lightning strike]. So, while fascinating to look at, those are not reliable indicators of [just] the electric field.

Comment: @robphy as we can see in James Lincoln's videos, electric fields are not perfectly straight as we can see from the plasma balls and from the single point charge where grass seeds are put in oil. I thought perfectly straight can be found in nature.

Comment: @SnoopyKid An electric field is a vector at every point in space. A “field line” is an https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integral_curve . Not all “field lines” are straight lines.